# In Meteor, how to make a form load prepopulated from a previously inserted object pulled from a MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, meteor

I just finished building a long-ish form field to let users input a lot of information. It has a bunch of text and number fields, some radiobutton sets, some checkboxes groups. It's being correctly stored in a Mongo collection, no problems.

Now I want to build a second routed page that will load the exact same html form, but I need to javascript to prepopulate all the fields with the previously added information pulled from the collection using the object id (passed via data context by the router).

I know this must be easy, but I'm not well versed in javascript yet, and the searches I did couldn't quite present me with a simple enough answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the inserted document in a helper and use it in html to render the form details.

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  formData:function(){
    return CollectionName.findOne({_id: documenteId});
  }
})


<template name ="templateName">
    {{#with fromData}}
        <form id="detailsForm" method="post">
          <label> Name </label>
          <input type="text" id=""  placeholder="name" value="{{name}}">

          <label> Description</label>
          <textarea  id="" placeholder="Description" >{{description}}</textarea>
           ..
          </div>
        </form>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: But this wouldn't work with a dynamic document, right? Because I'd have to hardcore the document id on the helper. The form I'm trying to build is the edit form for the person to edit the form that him/herself posted in the first place, so it will have to be loaded with different information for each user. (I'm sorry if I'm being dumb and objecting in an answer that would work, tough.)

Comment: No, you don't have to hardcode the id. You can use Router params or a session variable to identify the selected document id. i.e. If the user goes to the edit page get the id from the params or if you have some edit button where user can click and go the edit page, set a session variable on the button click.